# Should I Include Words Model, Service, Mediator in Event Names

Tags: robotlegs

If an event is dispatched by a service should I include the word 'service' in the event class name? For Example `TwitterServiceEvent`. The same applies to Models and Mediators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In robotlegs book "Actionscript Developers Guide to Robotlegs" they are not using it that way:

```
_remoteService.addEventListener(TwitterEvent.OVER_CAPACITY, dispatchOverCapacity);
```

But if you want it and it helps you, you can have it, why not.
I use signals, but when I name signals, I name them the same as the command is named with different suffix:

```
ConfigureViewSignal
ConfigureViewCommand
```

Also, did you check out AS3 Signals and SignalCommandMap for robotlegs?
https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals
https://github.com/robertpenner/robotlegs-extensions-SignalCommandMap

Comment: "..if you want it and it helps you, you can have it.." - i agree. The main thing (other than suitable names of course) is to be consistent with your naming strategy.

Comment: @Matej Šimunić shouldn't you capitalize the first letter of class names like `ConfigureViewSignal` — it looks very odd not to.